# How do I use this custom pipe

Tags: angular

I came across this [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lentschi/8600f9b6ea7e7f5178f40a36f3053de7/raw/9c32d815f65fd88e35513fb092c893c0f09a52de/replace-emojis.pipe.ts) which is a custom pipe to convert strings to emojis. I attempted to try this out via a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pt-emoji) and I don't believe that it is working.

How would I use this pipe ?

Answer (score 1):

you misonfigured Angular Module.

check my solution (btw I didn't use pipes)

in app.module.ts

```
import { EmojiModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/ngx-emoji';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ..., EmojiModule ],
  ...
})
```

in app.components.ts

```
<ngx-emoji [emoji]='name' size="16"></ngx-emoji>
```

in angular.json under styles

```
"../node_modules/@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker.css"
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pt-emoji-qecrvp)

Comment: oh right you used ngx-emoji to output the emoji. thanks

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer. thank you

Comment: Hi Simonare, I tried ngx-emoji and also attempted to generate the component dynamically and insert it into the dom. However, with this approach is it possible to use ngx-emoji and insert it into a contenteditable div  ? I.e have a contenteditable div where the user is able to type in something and use the picker select the emoji ?

Comment: Just to clarify, the insertion of the component into the dom inserted the component as a sibling. I believe I am going to need to insert it into the specific caret position.